# JSON structure for a ticket reservation system with Firebase?

Tags: json, database, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently developing a ticket reservation system where the user should be able to choose an event, see a list of sections, a section contains a list of seats, thats either free or occupied/booked by another user. I've chosen to use Firebase as my backend, but got very little experience with databases and zero using JSON. How would I go about structuring a system like this?

This is what I got so far:

```
{
  "events" : {
    "e2017" : {
      "name" : "event 2017",
      "date" : "1490567256550"
    }
  },
  "eventSections" : {
      "e2017" : {
          "e2017-A" : {
            "isFull" : false,
            "totalSeats": 40,
            "bookedSeats": 20
          }
      }
  },

  "sectionSeats" : {
      "e2017-A" : {
          "A1": {
            "isBooked" : true,
            "bookedBy" : "userId"
          },
          "A2": {
            "isBooked" : false,
            "bookedBy" : false
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: That's an incredibly broad topic. Unless you already have a model and wonder about how to implement one specific use-case against it, I vote this is too broad for Stack Overflow to answer. Instead I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated my question to show the structure im looking to implement

Comment: I am curious if you ever came up with a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The following structure is an example structure for a very specific use case of your question. You had the following criteria:

```
1) user should be able to choose an event
2) see a list of sections
3) a section contains a list of seats
4) (seats are) either free or occupied/booked by another user
```

and a structure that meets that criteria

```
events
     event_0
        sections
          section_0
            seats
              seat_0: "free"
              seat_1: "occupied"
          section_1
            seats
              seat_0: "occupied"
              seat_1: "occupied"
      event_1
        sections
          section_0
            seats
              seat_0: "free"
              seat_1: "occupied"
          section_1
            seats
              seat_0: "occupied"
              seat_1: "occupied"
```

While this is *an* answer, it's not the only one. For example. What if you wanted to know which events had free seats? You really can't query this structure for that data (unless you filter in code).

However, if you present a list of events to a user where they can click on the event to get more data, this structure would work fine as it could be used to present sections and seats available.

If you have a different specific use case, update your question with more data.